# How to use KMeans for distance clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataframe with X and Y axis values

They don't have any labels

They look as shown below

| X-COORDINATE | Y-COORDINATE |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |
| 90 | 27 |
| 49 | 64 |

Is it possible to use KMeans for clustering the data?

How do I get the labels and plot the data on a graph for each cluster?

Comment: Have you tried KMeans from sklearn? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: You sound confused; how could you get the labels from data that, as you say, have no labels? Plus, KMeans (and clustering in general) do not need (or take into account) labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use k-means even if you don't have labels because k-means is an unsupervised method, but...

First of all you need to **scale** your data, because k-means is a **distance** algorithm and using distances between data points to determine their similarity. More about that [here](https://towardsai.net/p/data-science/how-when-and-why-should-you-normalize-standardize-rescale-your-data-3f083def38ff).
I found [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/k-means-clustering-python/) for clustering very useful, you could start with that. It also describes how to plot your data first with silhouette or elbow plot to **define perfect number of clusters**.

It should look somewhat like that:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters) # you can get n_clusters from silhouette/elbow plot or just try out different numbers

kmeans_model.fit(your_dataframe)

labels = kmeans_model.predict(your_dataframe)

print(labels)
```

K-Means is not always performing perfect, if you want to get better results, you could also try out other algorithms like [DBSCAN, HDBSCAN, Agglomerative clustering...](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html). It always depends on your data which one you should choose.